# Ruby, MS Access - Differing query results

Tags: ruby, ms-access

I am periodically handed an MS Access database with a number of tables and the corresponding data. I am writing a script in Ruby (1.9.3) to query that database for information that I need, and then iterate over the results to generate additional data from.

I've noticed that the exact same sql string in Ruby as in MS Access does not return the same set of data, and I haven't been able to figure out why.

The limited number of other issues I am seeing are all related to "where" criteria, which doesn't exist in my SQL, or variables within the SQL, which also don't exist. It's a fixed text string that if I paste it into Access and run, it returns 559,283 rows of data, but if I run through the Ruby WIN32OLE connection, it only returns 69,773 rows of data (which do exist in the 559,283 set).

It's a complicated join, but as it's an identical SQL string between the two locations, I am at a loss as to why there are different results.

OLE connection and SQL statement: (ACES vehicle enhanced standard database in case anyone is familiar with it)

```
connection = WIN32OLE.new('ADODB.Connection')
connection.open('Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=<redacted>.accdb')

recordset = WIN32OLE.new('ADODB.Recordset')
sql = "SELECT Vehicle.VehicleID, BaseVehicle.BaseVehicleID, BaseVehicle.YearID, Make.MakeName, Model.ModelName, SubModel.SubModelName, EngineConfig.EngineConfigID, EngineBase.Liter, EngineBase.Cylinders, EngineBase.BlockType, CylinderHeadType.CylinderHeadTypeName, EngineDesignation.EngineDesignationName, FuelType.FuelTypeName, TransmissionNumSpeeds.TransmissionNumSpeeds, TransmissionControlType.TransmissionControlTypeName, TransmissionMfrCode.TransmissionMfrCode, DriveType.DriveTypeName, VehicleToTransmission.TransmissionID FROM TransmissionControlType INNER JOIN (FuelType INNER JOIN (EngineBase INNER JOIN (CylinderHeadType INNER JOIN (EngineDesignation INNER JOIN (DriveType INNER JOIN (TransmissionMfrCode INNER JOIN (TransmissionNumSpeeds INNER JOIN (TransmissionBase INNER JOIN (Transmission INNER JOIN ((((SubModel INNER JOIN ((Model INNER JOIN (Make INNER JOIN BaseVehicle ON Make.MakeID = BaseVehicle.MakeID) ON Model.ModelID = BaseVehicle.ModelID) INNER JOIN Vehicle ON BaseVehicle.BaseVehicleID = Vehicle.BaseVehicleID) ON SubModel.SubModelID = Vehicle.SubModelID) INNER JOIN VehicleToDriveType ON Vehicle.VehicleID = VehicleToDriveType.VehicleID) INNER JOIN (EngineConfig INNER JOIN VehicleToEngineConfig ON EngineConfig.EngineConfigID = VehicleToEngineConfig.EngineConfigID) ON Vehicle.VehicleID = VehicleToEngineConfig.VehicleID) INNER JOIN VehicleToTransmission ON Vehicle.VehicleID = VehicleToTransmission.VehicleID) ON Transmission.TransmissionID = VehicleToTransmission.TransmissionID) ON TransmissionBase.TransmissionBaseID = Transmission.TransmissionBaseID) ON TransmissionNumSpeeds.TransmissionNumSpeedsID = TransmissionBase.TransmissionNumSpeedsID) ON TransmissionMfrCode.TransmissionMfrCodeID = Transmission.TransmissionMfrCodeID) ON DriveType.DriveTypeID = VehicleToDriveType.DriveTypeID) ON EngineDesignation.EngineDesignationID = EngineConfig.EngineDesignationID) ON CylinderHeadType.CylinderHeadTypeID = EngineConfig.CylinderHeadTypeID) ON EngineBase.EngineBaseID = EngineConfig.EngineBaseID) ON FuelType.FuelTypeID = EngineConfig.FuelTypeID) ON TransmissionControlType.TransmissionControlTypeID = TransmissionBase.TransmissionControlTypeID;"
recordset.Open(sql, connection)
cars = recordset.GetRows.transpose
```

cars.length => 69773

Exact sql string pasted into Access: 559,283 rows.

I am using Aptana Studio 3 for my Ruby environment, run on Win7 64bit

Any ideas?

Edit:
Additionally, this isn't a limitation on the connection, as I have a 2nd query that returns 521,000 rows from the same database through Ruby, 516,000 rows when run through Access directly.

All queries run in approximately the same amount of time between Access vs Ruby

Comment: I have a few, but none that don't involve magical incantations or an atom bomb.  Holy crap,  why do you need so many joins?

Comment: It's the product of someone taking the concept of "normalization" to incomprehensible OCD status. It took me a few days to figure out that is the query that would return the results I need.

Comment: Are you accessing a VCdb?  (Yes, I know ACES.)  FWIW, I believe your bigger number:  in SQLServerMgmtStudio, your query & my VCdb gave ~560k rows. (A normal difference:  VCdb updates come out monthly.) Not a prob with dups:  same rowcount with `SELECT DISTINCT`.  However, I have not used (or even seen) parentheses in an INNER JOIN before, with a bunch of `ON` clauses at the end... did ACCESS generate that?  Would Ruby and Access see the same JOIN-to-JOIN dependency?  Do rowcounts match if each `ON` clause immediately follows its JOIN?  Or, compare rowcounts on smaller queries, and build up.

Comment: Yes, Access generated the SQL string. I don't know the answers to those questions, but I'm going to start getting them. A differing join interpretation could indeed be the problem, and not caught on my end since joins are my weak point in SQL.
(Yes, I am using the 1st or 2nd iteration of the DB to get this solid, and I will then be cycling through the iterations since so we have our own record of the changes).

Thanks

Comment: Sounds familiar ;) ...interested in the results.  (FYI, I did not get a comment-response-notification, because your comment was not posted on an answer from me, and your comment did not contain @Doug_Ivison.  I just chose to check-back anyway.)

Comment: @Doug_Ivison sorry, I've used SO for years for problem solving, but the first time I've ever had to ask a question :)

I rebuilt the Access db on a MySQL db, and then rebuilt the query piece by piece. It becomes terminally non-responsive after 10 inner joins. I think I'm going to change my approach completely and achieve my goal in another way. Still a puzzling question, but I can't let it hold me up.

Comment: Using SQL Server, I've gotten about 15 inner joins to VCdb to work, but only for a query that selects a small set of data.  What solves this, for me:  separate, cumulative `SELECT`s, with maybe 1 to 3 JOINs per SELECT -- you'll be amazed what that can do for performance.  Three approaches:  (1--my favorite) `SELECT INTO` to save into a table, then the next query with a few JOINs is `FROM` that table... so each `SELECT INTO` adds a few columns.  Or: (2) Start by `CREATE`ing a table with all the output columns, and use multiple `UPDATE`s, that each populate a few columns. Or: (3) Use subqueries.